# Parse json response from DispatchCommandResult

Tags: windows, cordova

This is not as simple as it sounds..  This started as a query, but before submitting I played a bit more and finally figured it out.. Now feeling a bit of a fool that it took a good couple of hours to find where the problem lay so thought I would leave the solution here in case anyone else finds this.

While making a plugin for phonegap/windows phone I hit a roadblock when trying to parse the json response from c#.  The json string is constructed as specified:

```
 To pass structured object data back to JS, it should be encoded as a JSON string:

 DispatchCommandResult(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, "{result:\"super awesome!\"}"));
```

This unfortunately throws an error and results in a string that you can split up but cannot do much else with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct construction is:

```
DispatchCommandResult(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, "{\"result\":\"super awesome!\"}"));
```

Which is parsed as a json and results in a response that can be immediately referenced:

```
response.result; = 'super awesome!'
```

Hope this helps someone else.